# How to send email using Slim framework email functionality?

Tags: php, email, slim

I would like to send an email to a user if they make an API call from an IOS app to my web application.

i.e. `http://testurl.com/forgotpassword/test@email.com`

In the above url - "test@email.com" is the user email to whom I want to send an email with a link to another URL in the email body.  For example, `http://testurl.com/resetpassword/test@email.com_44646464646`

My web application uses the Slim framework, within which I plan to define the following routes:

```
$app->get('/forgotpassword/:id', function($id) use ($app) {
    // from here i want to send email 
}

$app->get('/resetpassword/:id/:param', function($id, $param) use ($app) {
    // from here i want to update password
}
```

How can I send my email using Slim?

Comment: Slim has nothing to help you with email sending. You can use PHP's `mail` function or 3rd party library. Email will be available in `$id` variable.

Comment: ok thanks .could you please tell me how to render view file of forgot password with -New password and confirm password with validation with slim framework.                                                                                                                    because $app->get('/forgotpassword/:id', function($id) use ($app) {
  from here i want to send email 
}
using above code i have to redirect page to resetpassword page            $app->get('/resetpassword/:id/:param', function($id, $param) use ($app) {
from here i want to update password with view file and mail functionality
}

Comment: Its complete using PHP Mailer.

Answer (score 6):

Slim doesn't have any built-in mail functionality.  After all, it is a "Slim" microframework.

As one of the commenters suggested, you should use a third-party package like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

In PHPMailer:

```
$app->get('/forgotpassword/:id', function($id) use ($app) {
    $param = "secret-password-reset-code";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->setFrom('admin@badger-dating.com', 'BadgerDating.com');
    $mail->addAddress($id);
    $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@badger-dating.com', 'BadgerDating.com');

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Instructions for resetting the password for your account with BadgerDating.com';
    $mail->Body    = "
        <p>Hi,</p>
        <p>            
        Thanks for choosing BadgerDating.com!  We have received a request for a password reset on the account associated with this email address.
        </p>
        <p>
        To confirm and reset your password, please click <a href=\"http://badger-dating.com/resetpassword/$id/$param\">here</a>.  If you did not initiate this request,
        please disregard this message.
        </p>
        <p>
        If you have any questions about this email, you may contact us at support@badger-dating.com.
        </p>
        <p>
        With regards,
        <br>
        The BadgerDating.com Team
        </p>";

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $app->flash("error", "We're having trouble with our mail servers at the moment.  Please try again later, or contact us directly by phone.");
        error_log('Mailer Error: ' . $mail->errorMessage());
        $app->halt(500);
    }     
}
```

Comment: Not working for me, wonder what I'm doing wrong... Is there a `require` line somewhere to load PHPMailer in? In my project I've installed it using composer. That **should** be enough for `$mail = new PHPMailer` to work right?

Comment: @ZachCook you probably need the fully qualified class name for `PHPMailer`.  Either as a `use` statement, or in the `new` statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can easily send mail from slim framework using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Here is full code of `index.php`, that will make your sense that what actually the code is doing.

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

//From PHPMailer
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Require autoload.php of PHPMailer
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->post('/forgotpassword',function(Request $request, Response $response)
{
        $requestParamter = $request->getParsedBody();
        $email =  $requestParamter['email'];
        $id = $requestParamter['id'];
        sendVerificationEmail($email,$id);

});


//Function to send mail, 
function sendVerificationEmail($email,$id)
{      
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->SMTPDebug=3;
    $mail->isSMTP();

    $mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port=587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure="tls";
    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->Username="socialcodia@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password="12345";

    $mail->addAddress($email,"User Name");
    $mail->Subject="Verify Your Email Address For StackOverFlow";
    $mail->isHTML();
    $mail->Body=" Welcome to StackOverFlow.<b><b> Please verify your email adress to continue..";
    $mail->From="SocialCodia@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName="Social Codia";

    if($mail->send())
    {
        echo "Email Has Been Sent Your Email Address";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed To Sent An Email To Your Email Address";
    }


}


$app->run();
```