# How to send emails using Eloquent and Slim2

Tags: php, eloquent, phpmailer, slim-2

I have a doubt that how to send emails using Eloquent and slim2 framework.Can anyone help me to get out of this doubt please...

Comment: see this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358804/how-to-send-email-using-slim-framework-email-functionality**

Comment: @SandipND Now i am going to use php mailer for this..thank you

Comment: welcome sir, if any help comment here

Comment: Sure sir, if i need any help i will ask